# Dynamically splitting an array depending on character count

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, split

I have an array like so:

```
const testArray = [ 'blah', 'abc​testtt​​', 'atestc​', 'testttttt' ]
```

I would like to split the string once it reaches a certain character count, for example lets use 10 characters. Also, I would like the output to swap itself to be able to use within 10 characters. Please see the expected output below if this doesn't really make sense to you. Please assume that each item in the array will not be above 10 characters just for example purpose.

So once the `testArray` reaches 10 characters I would like the next item to be under a new variable maybe? Not sure if thats the best way of doing this.

Something like this maybe? Again this may be very inefficient, if so please feel free to use another method.

```
const testArray = [ 'blah', 'abctesttt​​', 'atestc', 'testttttt' ]
if ((testArray.join('\n')).length) >= 10 {
    /* split the string into parts and store it under a variable maybe?
    console.log((the_splitted_testArray).join('\n')); */

}
```

### **Expected output:**

```
"blah
atestc" //instead of using "abctesttt" it would use "atestc" as it's the next element in the array and it also avoids reaching the 10 character limit, if adding "atestc" caused the character limit to go over 10, I would like it to check the next element and so on

"abctesttt" // it can't add the remaining "testttttt" since that would cause the character limit to be reached

"testttttt"
```

Comment: What if a value has a length greater than 10?

Comment: @HassanImam Please assume that will not occur, I will add an edit for this. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: ***"//instead of using "```test```" it would use "`test`" to avoid reaching the 10 character limit"*** Other than `\`` Are there any other specific chars you consider as whitespace?

Comment: @zer00ne I'm not considering ``` as whitespace, each ` would count as 1 character.

Comment: You want to remove consecutive  `\`` down to one when testing. Collapsing whitespace is the same method. ***"\`\`\`test\`\`\`" it would use "`test`"***

Comment: @zer00ne Sorry if I wasn't clear I don't want to collapse the ` character. I just used it as an example, consider ` the same as a normal character. The reason it uses \`test\` instead is as using \`\`\`test\`\`\`  is to avoid going over the 10 character limit, as `"test\`\`\`test\`\`\`"` would total up to a 14 characters and `"test\`test\`"` would total up to 10 characters (which is useable)

Comment: Please explain this: ***"\`\`\`test\`\`\`" it would use "\`test\`"*** How do you determine what should be tested and not tested? What's the criteria? A char is a char is a char.

Comment: @zer00ne Please check the edit on my previous comment. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I've also made an edit to the question to clear up confusion. Sorry about this.

Comment: ***"Please assume that each item in the array will not be above 10 characters just for example purpose."*** Thank you for the edit, that clears things up. So if `element 0` is only 5 chars and `element 1` is 6 chars, `element 0` and `element 1` are combined and the 11th char goes to `element 2`?

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. And if `element 0` is only 5 chars and `element 1` is 6 chars, I would like to separate `element 1` from the output of `element 0` as I would like to keep the words in each element without splitting the characters, in other words I would like to separate the whole element if the character limit is reached.

Comment: Ok so if both elements combined are 10 or less then they can join

Comment: @zer00ne Correct. As long as the total character count for the resulted join is below 10 characters.

Comment: Is this linear? Example: element 0 compared to element 1 and element 1 (if it hasn't been joined with element 0) can only be compared to element 2, and so on. Nevermind I see that algorithm leapfrogs. +1 this is not frivolous and not easy.

Comment: @zer00ne Yes, that would be right. It doesn't necessarily have to leapfrog. Linear would also be feasible for my use and thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: My pedestrian way of explaining: `'blah', 'abctesttt​​', 'atestc'` `'abctesttt​​'` is skipped. Jaspa's suggestion to use a 2 dimensional array is a good way to go.

Comment: @zer00ne Ah okay I see, thanks for the simple explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as you can't create a new variable out of nowhere at run time, you are probably going to use a "parent"-array, which then contains the actual strings with a length of 10 maximally.

For the grouping you probably have to design an algorithm yourself. My first idea for an algorithm is something like below. Probably not the best and most efficient way (as the description of "efficient" depends on your personal priorities), but feel free to optimise it yourself :)

1. Walk through `$testArray[]`, sort all strings into a new two-dimensional array: `$stringLength[$messagesWithSameLength[]]`. Like `array(1=>array('.','a'),2=>array('hi','##',...),...)`
2. Now, always try to get as many strings together as possible. Start with one of the longest strings, calculate the remaining space and get a string suiting best into it. If none fits, start a new group.

Always try to use the space as good as possible

Comment: Maybe `strlen()`? :D PHP has an awesome documentation, did you know ;) Google is always your friend there

Comment: PHP? But I'm using JavaScript and implementing this in a Node.js environment.

Comment: Whoops, shame on me xD But also there: Google ^^ It's really not hard to find

Comment: I have no problem I was being facetious ;)